Electron Builder is not working Correctly
I am using Electron Builder ver. 25.0.5 and this error message keeps popping up
                    errorOut=ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : C:\Users\Ardne\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\074573135\darwin\10.12\lib\libcrypto.dylib
    ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : C:\Users\Ardne\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\074573135\darwin\10.12\lib\libssl.dylib

                    command='C:\Users\Ardne\OneDrive\Desktop\my-new-app\node_modules\7zip-bin\win\x64\7za.exe' x -bd 'C:\Users\Ardne\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\074573135.7z' '-oC:\Users\Ardne\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\074573135'
                    workingDir=C:\Users\Ardne\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign
  • Above command failed, retrying 0 more times 

does anyone have anyway to fix this?
I checked to see if i had the installations and i followed some tutorials and this did not work
